# EF Core 6 very slow in OnModelCreating to run first query

Tags: entity-framework-core

I've scaffolded a very large Oracle db of around 2500 tables.

I've written a trivial app, using Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore (6.21.5) to open a connection a query < 100 rows.

When u run the app it spends a long long time (> 10 minutes) in OnModelCreating.

I understand that its generating the mapping from the db into the EF model, and that this is a common issue.

I've installed EF Core Tools (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools) to see if i can pregenerate views (some magic), but that doesnt seem to exist.

I've seen https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/pre-generated-views, but this seems very sketchy about how to do this. I would have thought there was some example code somewhere to take a model, save the views and then reload them on startup.

I've also used (as suggested by Svyatoslav)
dotnet ef dbcontext optimize
which seemed to spend a lot of time doing something then said

```
Successfully generated a compiled model, to use it call 'options.UseModel(ModelContextModel.Instance)'
```

but what does that actually mean?

the only obvious place to put it is here

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseModel(ModelContextModel.Instance)
                .UseOracle("User Id=psi.....;");
        }
    }
```

but "ModelContextModel.Instance" doesnt exist, and its not obvious what this should be

(Im not actually too clear that its actually done anything except output lots of warnings and this message)

---

i have now got this to work by explicitly defining the output folder and dbcontext in my example application.

It now takes about 10 seconds to initialise my model, which actually in my context is still not ideal, but much better than 10 minutes.

I'll try and write up the answer properly tomorrow.

Comment: Scaffold only needed tables. EF requires full Model initialisation, so better to avoid so many tables. Also maybe [Compiled Models](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-6-0-preview-5-compiled-models/) can help here.

Comment: ah ok, the use case really requires all the tables - its for a reporting module that can query anywhere. Let me look at compiled models

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - I've tried that but there is a cryptic message it gives me that doesnt make any sense to me.

Comment: Anyway, EF is not designed for reporting and such big databases and you will encounter later a lot of performance issues with complex LINQ queries and LINQ Translator limitations. So take in account that exists [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) it do not require full model initialisation and do mapping initialisation only for requested entities, which is fast.

Comment: i must admit to being surprised about even the compiled model performance. At the moment im in POC stage, and I need a mechanism to scaffold as quickly as possible, but i'll look into linq2db further.

Comment: It easy to scaffold by `linq2db`, but currently only via T4 templates on Windows. In v4 will be introduced scaffold tool which works similar to EF's scaffold. If you need help, just drop message in linq2db's github discussions.